# PHP Filehandling, code never reached

Tags: php

I've got a piece of code with some error i've been trying to find all day... what this (should) does is: go through all the files in a folder, check if it's a image type, if it is, create a thumbnail in some folder. It does the job BUT: it doesnt continue afterwards, I put a echo command and its never executed. I apprechiate any help! thanks alot.

```
$bilddateitypen     = array('gif','jpg','JPG','GIF');

$importdir          = '../sync';
if ($handle = opendir($importdir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        if (!is_dir($importdir."/".$file) && is_file($importdir."/".$file)) {
            $ex = explode('.',$file);
            if(in_array($ex[count($ex)-1], $bilddateitypen)) {

                $file = utf8_decode($file);
                $thumbnail = new thumbnail($importdir."/".$file);
                $thumbnail->jpeg_quality(93);
                $thumbnail->save("../shop/images/product_images/original_images/".$file);
                $thumbnail->size_auto(500);
                $thumbnail->save("../shop/images/product_images/popup_images/".$file);
                $thumbnail->size_auto(200);
                $thumbnail->save("../shop/images/product_images/info_images/".$file);
                $thumbnail->size_auto(112);
                $thumbnail->save("../shop/images/product_images/thumbnail_images/".$file);


            } else {
                continue;   
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
echo "Hallo Welt";
```

Comment: Please show us (in your code sample) where the `echo` doesn't execute.

Comment: Also, please change `false !== ($file = readdir($handle))` to `($file = readdir($handle)) !== false`. The way you have it will technically work, but it reads backwards.

Comment: i put the echo command under the if command and the code segment given here.

Comment: ***put it in the code sample*** there are three `if` statements.

Comment: Do you want it to `continue` or to `break` where you have the `continue` command? There's a big difference.

Comment: continue, the else executes when the file in the directory is not a picture file (jpg, gif...) but the next one might be a pic again. So it must be continue, right?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I was just making sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never update the value of `$handle` within the `while` loop, therefore creating an infinite loop.

Comment: in my understandig $handle is the rescource to the opend folder. what do you mean with update? It should stop when all files passed the while loop...

Comment: `($file = readdir($handle)) !== false` controls your `while` loop. If this doesn't update, you'll never get out of the loop. You may as well just write `while(true)`.

Comment: but readdir returns the next filename and when there are no more files it returns false, so it says here anyway... [link](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Comment: aahh, could it be that the false is written into the $file string as a string an then never 'not idential' to the boolean false?

Answer (score 0):

Try run code only with echo without resizing images. Try var_dump variables and check what is in. Make sure you have error reporting on. If some error occur.

Check image extension this way:

```
public static function isImage($fileName)
{
    $type = exif_imagetype($fileName);

    if (!(($type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) || ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($type == IMAGETYPE_PNG)))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: if I comment out the image resizing section it runs through!

Comment: When problem is in image resize. Inspire in SimpleImage class. http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: my resize function has problems with certain kinds of jpegs (the ones i shot with my nikon...) thats the problem...

Comment: so it works fine now?
And use the function for checking images what I wrote above. It reads first rows of file and check file type. Cause the image can have no extension and a php script can have jpg extension (it wont work but it is not iamge and script failed because cannot resize php script) ;)